# How to Update Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.4 using CentOS Repos

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, rhel5

I don't have a subscription for RHEL anymore and I want to update my server. Can anyone tell me How to Update Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.4 using CentOS Repos ?

Answer (score 8):

Ok i figured out. I created a file CentOs.repo (/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOs.repo) with the following contents :

```
[CentOS-Base]
name=CentOS-Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=5&arch=$basearch&repo=os
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5

[CentOS-Updates]
name=CentOS-Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=5&arch=$basearch&repo=updates
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5

[CentOS-Plus]
name=CentOS-Plus
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=5&arch=$basearch&repo=centosplus
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
```

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, you just install the approprate `centos-release` package, and then run `yum upgrade` (or `yum update` if you don't want to obsolete anything).

Comment: Can you please elaborate how i can do that.

Comment: yum update and yum upgrade do the same thing; yum update has an option for obsoletes which defaults to the same setting that yum upgrade uses. You can change the default with an option to yum update.

Answer (score -2):

http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/

http://apt.sw.be/

rpm -Uhv http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/i386/rpmforge/RPMS/rpmforge-release-0.3.6-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm

use this and update it work chkconfig rhnsd off

Comment: This is not an official CentOS repository. It is RPMForge